# How to copy/paste selected columns from one xls to another

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I would like to copy/paste some columns (always the same) from one Workbook to another. I can't make my code to do this between workbooks.
And one more small thing I want paste values to the 4th row in target sheet and all I could do by myself is to paste it into second one :/

Something like this code but this one works only pasting values from one sheet to another in the same xls file:

EDIT: code with my attempt of copy/paste between xls files. What do I do wrong, because it doesn't work.

```
    Sub Paste_columns()

Dim x As Worksheet, r As Long, y As Worksheet

Set x = Workbooks("Bench.xlsm").Worksheets("Test-Sheet")
Set y = Workbooks("Pres.xls").Worksheets("Paste_tab")
With y
   For r = 2 To y.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If y.Cells(r, 2).Value > 0 Then
        x.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Cells(r, 2)
        x.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Cells(r, 3)
        x.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Cells(r, 4)
        x.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Cells(r, 5)
        x.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Cells(r, 8)
        x.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Cells(r, 9)
        x.Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Cells(r, 13)
        x.Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Cells(r, 15)
        x.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Cells(r, 17)
        x.Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Cells(r, 19)
        x.Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Cells(r, 22)
        x.Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = .Cells(r, 23)
            Else: End
        End If

    Next r

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you already search at SO??? There are several questions in this site similar than yours.

Comment: Yes, but adding Workbook("bla.xls").Worksheet("bla") - does not work :/ or I am doing a mistake. And I still don't know how to deal with pasting first copied row into 4th row in target sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've did something like this and it works properly. Thanks to the @Harassed Dad - I've used some of your code. I think it could be more universal but for me it's OK now.

```
Sub PasteToTemplate()

Dim xD As Workbook
Dim xS As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim x As Worksheet
Dim tempN As Worksheet
Dim tN As String
Dim sN As String

With Sheets("Source_sample_size")
    sN = .Range("PresName").Value
End With

Set xS = Workbooks(sN)
Set wsSource = xS.Worksheets("Paste_tab")

Set tempN = xS.Worksheets("Source_sample_size")

With tempN
    tN = .Range("tempName").Value
  End With

Set xD = Workbooks.Open(tN)
Set x = xD.Worksheets("Test-Sheet")


        wsSource.Range("A2:F" & wsSource.Range("A" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        x.Range("B4").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        wsSource.Range("H2:I" & wsSource.Range("A" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        x.Range("H4").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        wsSource.Range("J2:J" & wsSource.Range("A" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        x.Range("M4").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        wsSource.Range("K2:K" & wsSource.Range("A" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        x.Range("O4").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        wsSource.Range("L2:L" & wsSource.Range("A" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        x.Range("AI4").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        wsSource.Range("M2:M" & wsSource.Range("A" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        x.Range("AK4").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        wsSource.Range("P2:P" & wsSource.Range("A" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        x.Range("AM4").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use meaningful variable names - particularly when you are learning:

```
Sub Example()
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wbDestination As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
Dim rSource As Range
Dim rDestination As Range
Set wbSource = Workbooks("Pres.xls")
Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Paste_tab")

Set wbDestination = Workbooks("Bench.xlsm")
Set wsDestination = wbDestination.Worksheets("Test-Sheet")

Set rSource = wsSource.Range("b2:b" & wsSource.Range("b" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
For Each rDestination In wsDestination.Range("B4:W4")
    If InStr("BCDEHIMOQSVW", Left(rDestination.AddressLocal(False, False), 1)) > 0 Then

       ' rSource.Copy rDestination
  '=============if only values wanted ===========
        rsource.copy
        rdestination.pastespecial xlpastevalues
'==================
    End If
Next rDestination
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks GREAT but where should I specify that VALUES should be pasted because now it copies only formulas :)

Comment: As I've implement pastValues I can see that this code copies B column from source into all mentioned InStr columns :/ and not next mentioned column. Sorry for being such a nuisance.